# Merging two JSON strings in JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json as under

```
"chart": { 
        "xAxisname": "Months",
        "yAxisName": "Year"
    }
```

The second Json I am receiving from WebAPI as under

```
[
    {
        "productName": "Personal Loan",
        "loanAmount": [
            {
                "amount": 121000
            },            
            {
                "amount": 145000
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "productName": "Car Loan",
        "loanAmount": [
            {
                "amount": 180000
            },
            {
                "amount": 210000
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I am looking for an output as

```
{
    "chart": { 
        "xAxisname": "Months",
        "yAxisName": "Year"
    },    
    "dataset": [
        {
            "productName": "Personal Loan",
            "loanAmount": [
                {
                    "amount": "121000"
                },            
                {
                    "amount": "145000"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "productName": "Car Loan",
            "loanAmount": [
                {
                    "amount": "180000"
                },
                {
                    "amount": "210000"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried with **$.extend** of JQuery as under

```
var obj1 = { 
                    "xAxisname": "Months",
                    "yAxisName": "Year"
                    };

        var obj2 = [
                        {
                            "productName": "Personal Loan",
                            "loanAmount": [
                                {
                                    "amount": 121000
                                },            
                                {
                                    "amount": 145000
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "productName": "Car Loan",
                            "loanAmount": [
                                {
                                    "amount": 180000
                                },
                                {
                                    "amount": 210000
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                ];

        var finalObj = $.extend(obj1, obj2);
```

Though it is merging but not as  expected.

Comment: `var finalobj = { 'chart' : obj1, 'dataset': obj2 }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var obj1 = {
  "xAxisname": "Months",
  "yAxisName": "Year"
};

var obj2 = [{
  "productName": "Personal Loan",
  "loanAmount": [{
    "amount": 121000
  }, {
    "amount": 145000
  }]
}, {
  "productName": "Car Loan",
  "loanAmount": [{
    "amount": 180000
  }, {
    "amount": 210000
  }]
}];

var finalObj = $.extend({chart: obj1}, {dataset: obj2});

// or just

var otherObj = {
  chart: obj1,
  dataset: obj2
}

console.log( finalObj );
console.log( otherObj );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var j1 = 
   { 
        "xAxisname": "Months",
        "yAxisName": "Year"
    };


var j2 = [
    {
        "productName": "Personal Loan",
        "loanAmount": [
            {
                "amount": 121000
            },            
            {
                "amount": 145000
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "productName": "Car Loan",
        "loanAmount": [
            {
                "amount": 180000
            },
            {
                "amount": 210000
            }
        ]
    }
];

var j3 = {};
j3["chart"] = j1;
j3["dataset"] = j2;

console.log(JSON.stringify(j3));
```